# The website suddenly disappeared from Google SERP?

Tags: seo

My website disappeared from all the Google SERPs for which it ranks for! With no changes made - ranking restored in 15 days, and after 20 days - it's gone again.

If we search for the website name - it shows every page of it. While there are no manual actions, no black hat SEO or penalty type of stuff

It's just with Google, the website is on every other search engine

Answer (score 1):

Check first if you website is being indexed at all, try a search with "site:domain.test" (replacing with your website domain)

[image]

If you see results, that means that Google is indexing your website. If you see results, then your site is being indexed but maybe your content is not raking well.

If you don't get any results on Google for that search, then you have a bigger issue.

Do you have [sitemaps](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/sitemaps/build-sitemap) setup for your site correctly added on GoogleSearchConsole?

Check also your `robots.txt` configuration, if you don't see results on Google it could also be because you are blocking your site from being indexed, take a look to [this guide for reference](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/intro).

Finally, take a look to your HTML, and make sure you don't have any robots meta-tag blocking the robots as well, for example:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```